# Flask SQLAlchemy, Access many-to-many relationship after join

Tags: python, sql, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many relationship set up between `User` and `Paper` called `paperauthors`. I also have a one-to-many relationship set up between `Review` and `Paper`.

I cant figure out how to join the `Paper` and `Review` table without losing the ability to get the list of authors with `Paper.authors`.

Here is my model

```
paperauthors = db.Table('paperauthors',
                        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
                        db.Column('paper_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('papers.id'))
                        )


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)


class Paper(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'papers'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    abstract = db.Column(db.Text)
    authors = db.relationship("User",
                    secondary=paperauthors,
                    backref="papers")


class Review(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'reviews'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    paper = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('papers.id'))
    reviewer = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    evaluation = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

First I tried:

```
allReviews = Review.query.join(Paper).add_columns(Paper.title, Paper.authors,
                                                      Review.timestamp, Review.reviewer, 
                                                      Review.evaluation).all()
```

But the `.authors` field was a bool. I'm guessing this is because I'm operating in the context of the the database rows and columns, not the python `Paper` model.

I also tried:

```
allReviews = Paper.query.outerjoin(Review, Review.paper == Paper.id).all()
```

This way allowed me to access the `Paper.authors` method, but since I was operating in the context of the `Paper` python model, I could not access the `Review` fields of reviewer and evaluation.

What can I do to get the data from both tables including the many-to-many data?